# Raster overlay and analysis

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, rasterio

I have two raster files, of the same spatial area, but different granularity of spatial resolution. Specifically, one (say, A) has cells measuring 375x375m, and the other (say, B) has cells measuring 50x50m. The goal is as follows - for each cell in A, find out what cells of B lie in it, and calculate an aggregate measure of such cells (mean for example). I am currently doing this python by --

```
#create a pandas data frame from raster B
#for each cell x in A
#    find which cells in B lie in A through a dataframe search
```

Although this seems to do the job, for fairly large raster files, it is horribly slow. On a 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 MAC with 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7, this takes about 13 hours. Raster A has size 4000*4000, and raster B is naturally larger.

Any ideas about how I can do this directly in QGIS or PyQGIS?

Answer (score -1):

Try Raster Layer Zonal Statistics:

[image]